# Solutions to stop a glued up panel from flexing

Tags: panel, expansion

I glued up a panel using these 24" long cedar boards and because of the length (56") If I pick up the panel on one side, it flexes and feels like it's going to break on one of the glued joints. This panel is going to be a cover for a firepit so I want it as thin as possible. I was thinking of embedding some flat bar in it to make it more ridged but looking for alternatives too. Could I embed some poplar going lengthwise instead of metal? Would I have to worry about potential movement since I would be going against the grain on all of the boards?

[edit to address some comments]
I went in this direction because the boards I had were too small. I guess I could have glued up the boards to make longer boards and then glued them into a panel but I'm not sure if that would have been better.
I can screw in something on the bottom but I'm worried about movement if I did that. If I took a 1x2 lengthwise and put a single screw into each board that would make it much more stiff but would that allow for the movement it needs?

[image]

Comment: Too late now but this would have been much better built with the boards oriented lengthwise, so the long axis was aligned with the stiffer axis of wood. *"feels like it's going to break on one of the glued joints"* If you did the glue up well there's no danger of this as glued joints are stronger than the wood itself, although naturally it could split anywhere else :-)

Comment: *"Would I have to worry about potential movement since I would be going against the grain on all of the boards?"* Yes of course, the wider you make something the greater the total movement (one reason that typically tabletops aren't build this way). Flat bar would work in one respect, but you face the same issue of how to attach it so that it still allows the top to move. These days C-channel is sometimes used as a stiffener for wide counters and tabletops, and movement is accommodated by passing the screws at the ends through slots instead of round holes. But I presume [contd]

Comment: ...you don't have enough thickness here to attach something from the underside with screws? Very strong magnets might be a possible solution, but you'd have to be careful never to heat them up.

Comment: Metal or wood for the stiffeners doesn't matter, screws still need to go through slots to allow for movement, same as on the C-channel I mention. You generally fix the centre and allow for half the total movement each end & that makes the most sense here. You don't need to screw into every board, one central screw (per stiffener) + one each end may be enough. Add one halfway between if desired. But are you OK screwing through the face here, looks-wise? We can't tell, but the panel sure looks like it's too thin to allow sufficient bite if they come in from the bottom as you'd use on a tabletop.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a table top - stretcher attachment problem, and there are good solutions.   Simplest would be to make two or three stretchers and screw them underneath your panel.  To prevent wood movement from wrecking the construction you should fasten only the center of the stretchers immovably to the panel, and put all the screws from the center outward in elongated slots, so the panel can slide on the stretchers.   You can mill the slots with a spiral router bit.   From the fixed center, you need to accommodate 28" or less of "free" wood, so a 3/8" long slot should be sufficient.   If the wood is starting kiln dried, place the screws at or near the inboard ends of the slots.   If it's at summertime equilibrium moisture content, stay in the center, or toward the outboard end.  Use washer head screws, or screws with flats on the heads and separate washers.   One screw per board in each stringer will probably do, although two would be better, particularly since the boards won't accept very deep screws..

If that's too hard, or you lack the tools, get some slotted c-channel instead of making the stretchers.

Answer (score 0):

> I can screw in something on the bottom but I'm worried about movement if I did that

This is a reasonable worry, as the movement with the grain oriented as it is won't be insignificant.

This is because the grain is oriented with the short axis, and as movement is across the grain this arrangement maximises the potential expansion and contraction along the long axis of the panel.

Do bear in mind that actual movement is directly based on how much the local conditions change with the seasons. You can look up the average high and low RH for your location and based on that fairly accurately calculate the EMC<sup>1</sup>, and hence expected movement in service, or you can simply err on the side of caution and allow for a lot. As there's no penalty for doing the second that's the route I'd advise; this way you can be sure that no matter what the weather throws at you in the future you'll be covered. Given how weather is changing globally this may be prudent.

> If I took a 1x2 lengthwise and put a single screw into each board that would make it much more stiff but would that allow for the movement it needs?

No it wouldn't, in fact it would be most likely to cause an issue.

For a start you don't need to screw into every board. The panel should be assumed to be structurally sound so 3-5 screws (per stiffener) may be sufficient...

*...that is, IF the screws have sufficient bite in the panel.*

In the photo the panel looks too thin to securely screw in from the bottom, the way you'd typically attach a tabletop to expansion plates, buttons, Z-clips etc.

While there's no hard-and-fast rule a useful rule of thumb is that you need at least three threads for a proper hold, and the softer the wood the more thread engagement you'd want for confidence that you won't get pull-out.

Based on this, I think mounting the stiffeners using strong magnets is a possible solution, but note that with many magnets you have to make sure they never get hot<sup>2</sup>.

Since this is for the cover of a firepit *and* with directly face the sky in use, drilling through would be a surer bet. You'd mount with nuts and bolts/machine screws for metal strips, or regular screws for thicker wood stiffeners; the screw/bolt heads can be mounted flush in countersinks or below flush in counterbores if preferred.

**To allow for movement, screws go through slots**
You're arranging for the panel to expand outwards from the centre at both ends, so the central screws simply pass through drilled holes as normal.

So, how long do the slots at each end of the stiffening plates or battens need to be? Luckily cedar doesn't move a lot in service — this would be so much worse if made from hardwood! — so slots of 1/2" should be sufficient; note this is based on the outermost screws being roughly 25" from centre<sup>2</sup>.

As we're only just out of June and typically more-humid months lie ahead, *mount the outer screws close to the **far end** of each slot*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or, let someone else do it for you :-) See FPL document [Equilibrium Moisture Content of Wood in Outdoor Locations in the United States and Worldwide](https://www.esf.edu/wus/documents/EMCofWoodFPL268.pdf) (PDF warning).

<sup>2</sup> I've added a comfortable margin of error, for max possible movement in the wood, mounting not being possible exactly 25" from the centreline (i.e having to be further out), and greater EMC change than in published sources.

<sup>3</sup> Many common grades of rare-earth magnet permanently lose strength when heated, starting at temps below that of boiling water, 176°F (80°C). High-temp-stable magnets are available, example [here](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/proddetail.asp?prod=D61SH) but note these can withstand temps only up to 302°F (150°C).